# Ocaml - Syntax error when trying to compile

Tags: package, syntax-error, ocaml

i got this in my prog.ml:

```
#require "batteries";;
#require "Base";;
open Base;;
open Batteries;;
...
```

When I try to compile:

> ocamlc prog.ml -o prg

it returns the following error:

> 1 | #require "batteries";;
>
> ```
>   ^ Error: Syntax error
> ```

what is the correct command to compile the program?

Comment: Use Dune to set up your project: https://dune.build/

Comment: i use mac osx. I try "ocamlc -I </Users/manuel/.opam/system/lib/Base /Users/manuel/.opam/system/lib/Batteries> prog.ml -o prg" but the code inside the file "prog.ml" is deleted and does not generate the executable "prg".

Comment: It looks like your command is redirecting the output of `ocamlc` into your file `prog.ml` (because of the `>`). That's why the file seems to get 'deleted'. I strongly recommend using Dune as I mentioned above, it takes care of linking and building your project so you can focus on the code.

Comment: how to build the "dupe" file to compile? I tried something like this: (executable
   (name prog)
   (libraries /Users/xt/.opam/system/lib/Base /Users/xt/.opam/system/lib/Batteries) but it doesn't work. When I try: "dune build prog.exe" returns "Error: Library ... not found."

Comment: Hi @manuel I recommend asking this as a separate question.

Comment: "You have reached your question limit"

Comment: You can ask at discuss.ocaml.org, there is a big community of helpful people

Answer (score 2):

Lines starting with `#directive` are meaningful only in the toplevel. They're not part of the actual syntax of OCaml. They just tell the toplevel to do various things that are useful during an interactive session.

If you're going to compile the code (rather than interacting with it in the toplevel), you just need to make sure the modules are accessible to the compiler. You can use a fancy build system, or you can use the `-I` flag that tells the compiler where to look for modules.

(You also have to remove the `#directive` lines from your source code, of course.)

Comment: Something like "ocamlc -I Base Batteries Pervasives prog.ml -o prg"?

Comment: I try "ocamlc -I </Users/manuel/.opam/system/lib/Base /Users/manuel/.opam/system/lib/Batteries> prog.ml -o prg" but the code inside the file "prog.ml" is deleted and does not generate the executable "prg"...